# How to avoid the hyphen entered in the textfield using regular expressions?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I have a textfield where I am performing validations using regular expressions. But I have a problem when the user enters hyphen in the textfield and click on the button then an alert should be provided that no entered is not valid. I am performing validations for string and special characters but for special characters it is not getting validated.

This is my code:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [[[NSRegularExpression alloc]
                                               initWithPattern:@"[a-zA-Z][#$%&*()']" options:0 error:NULL] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check occurance of hyphen using `rangeOfString`

```
NSRange k = [str rangeOfString:@"-"];
if(k.length != 0)
  ... Show your alert message
```

I feel this will meet your requirements, No need to step in complexity if regexp..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with objective-c and it's flavor of regular expressions, and I'm not *completely* clear on what you are asking, but your regular expression will *not* match a hyphen. It should match a letter followed by one of the following characters: `#$%&*()'`. Below are a few examples of what should match and some things that should not match:

```
SHOULD MATCH              SHOULD NOT MATCH
----    ----            ----  ------  ------
 a#      a$              A     --      C3PO
 A)      A*              #     -       huh?
 T%      Q#              g-    AA##    123
 j&      a(              $R    ()      bbb5
 z'      B&              qq    "D%"    ()-
```

If any of these are inconsistent with what you want to match, then you need to ask a question containing the desired pattern that you want to match. Some examples would be:

- "any number of letters, parentheses, asterisks, ampersands"
- "any number of any character except hyphens and square brackets (`[]`)"
- "between one and three capital letters followed by an optional number"
- ...or whatever meets your requirements.

Regular Expressions are a language that allows specification of almost any pattern of text-based data. If you do not need to match a pattern, then regular expressions might not be necessary. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Don't show an alert because a user entered a character you don't like. That's terrible UX, especially when using a soft keyboard where typos are more likely.

Instead, process the input to extract the characters you do want. Think of a writing a web form with an input field for a phone number. You're not interested in the human-readable formatting in the phone number--the hyphens, the plus prefix to the country code, etc. But nothing should stop the user from entering those characters. You have code that can strip out the invalid characters leaving what you want.

`NSString` even makes this easy for you with `-stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`. You define an `NSCharacterSet` with the characters you want removed from a given `NSString` instance, invoke `-stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`, and you get an autoreleased `NSString` instance with only the characters you want in it, e.g.:

```
NSString          *rawInput; // value assigned elsewhere to @"555-555-1212"
NSCharacterSet    *characterSet = [ NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: @"-" ];
NSString          *processedInput = nil;

processedInput = [ rawInput stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: characterSet ];

NSLog( @"processedInput: %@", processedInput ); // logs "5555551212"
```